# Can't delete photo from iPad album

Tags: ios, alassetslibrary

I have used  ALAssetsLibrary for storing image in iPad album with Some folder name. Now I want to delete photo.
Is there any method to delete Photos from iPad album?

Comment: This question is probably better suited to this site: http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. The `ALAssetsLibrary` framework doesn't allow deleting assets from an album.